# Has the notion of 'semidet' in Prolog been settled?

Tags: annotations, prolog, evaluation, deterministic, non-deterministic

Being new to Prolog, I came across a very interesting [discussion](http://swi-prolog.996271.n3.nabble.com/call-semidet-1-clean-removal-of-choice-points-td11555.html) that happened in late 2012.
What I noticed was that there were, at the time, two notions of
'semidet' in Prolog community, namely:

1. A computation that succeeds at most once.
2. A computation that, upon success, leaves no choice points open.

Clearly the second one implies the first, but not vice versa.

Reading the thread, I understood that  the first one was
Dr.Neumerkel's notion, and the second was Drs.Wielemaker, O'Keefe, and others'.

Googling around, I've seen some database researchers mean by
'semi-deterministic' a query that would answer at most one equivalence
class, nearer to the first notion.

Dr. Neumerkel says (refering to the predicate called `call_semidet` there):

> The implementation might be improved, but prior to optimizing and
> bechnmarking the actual meaning needs to be settled.

So, has the meaning been settled?

### How about 'det'?

It seems customary to classify predicates according to their number
of solutions. According to the [SWI-Prolog's definition](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary) (see below), a 'det' can do fully
nondeterministic (say parallel) computations, provided it commits to
a solution which is now guaranteed to exist. So, by analogy I guess there
may be two notions of 'det':

1. A computation which succeeds exactly once.
2. A computation which succeeds exactly once *and* which, upon success, leaves
   no choice points.

The first one is more logical but undecidable in general until the end of the
computation. The second is easily decidable once a solution is found, but
procedural and its meaning depends on the particular search strategy Prolog
employs, i.e. the depth first search.

I wonder if there is not a community's consensus yet? Why not name
these two different concepts differently?

Here's the excerpt from the SWI-Prolog's page above:

> det [determinism]
>
> Short for deterministic.
>
> deterministic
>
> A predicate is deterministic if it succeeds exactly one time
> without leaving a choice point.
>
> semidet
>
> Shorthand for semi deterministic.
>
> semi deterministic
>
> A predicate that is semi deterministic either fails or succeeds
> exactly once without a choice point. See also deterministic.

Comment: "...the actual meaning needs to be settled." This quote actually referred to the user's programming process where we want to settle the meaning of a predicate. It was not meant to refer to settling the meaning of `call_semidet/1` which was already settled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a really excellent question!

From the [**Mercury determinism categories**](https://www.mercurylang.org/information/doc-latest/mercury_ref/Determinism-categories.html) where this is also explained quite authoritatively:

> ### 6.1 Determinism categories
>
> For each mode of a predicate or function, we categorise that mode **according to how many times it can succeed**, and whether or not it can fail before producing its first solution.
>
> If all possible calls to a particular mode of a predicate or function which return to the caller (calls which terminate, do not throw an exception and do not cause a fatal runtime error)
>
> - have exactly one solution, then that mode is deterministic (det);
> - **either have no solutions or have one solution, then that mode is semideterministic (semidet)**;
> - have at least one solution but may have more, then that mode is multisolution (multi);
> - have zero or more solutions, then that mode is nondeterministic (nondet);
> - have exactly zero solutions, i.e, fail without producing a solution, then that mode has a determinism of failure (failure).

(*emphases mine*)

Note that whether or not a choice point is left is not even mentioned in this definition, nor in the whole section. Mercury is not the same as Prolog, but the point is that this definition is in principle 100% applicable also to Prolog. Clearly, it then corresponds to your variant (1).

In my opinion, this is right in this way: Whether or not a *choice point* is left is rather immaterial, and depends on—for example—how powerful and versatile your system's **argument indexing** is. A good indexing scheme may prevent the creation of choice points that other systems introduce. A notion that depends on particular idiosyncrasies of a specific Prolog system and may break from one version to the next (with the introduction of better argument indexing etc.) is not very robust, and not of much value.

It is true that we often say "the predicate is deterministic" when we mean: "the predicate is deterministic and no choice points are left", but even so the main point is almost always also in such cases that the predicate **succeeds exactly once**. Note that "deterministic" is a rather overloaded adjective with other meanings too. In the SWI documentation, this ambiguity carries over to semi deterministic. However, even SWI back-pedals a bit from this rather implementation-oriented definition in [other places](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=testsemidet):

> #### 2.2.2 Testing semi-deterministic predicates
>
> Semi-deterministic predicates are predicates that either fail or succeed exactly once and, **for well behaved predicates**, leave no choicepoints.

So a semi-deterministic predicate that is not *well behaved* (?) can also leave choice points...

In the discussion, note especially the following: Ulrich is here using the weaker and **more robust** notion to obtain a predicate that is applicable **for both definitions**.

So, no matter which variant you pick, `call_semidet/1` is useful! From this, the meaning of the quote becomes clearer. When Ulrich says:

> (The implementation might be improved, but prior to optimizing and  bechnmarking the actual meaning needs to be settled.)

it is evidently *not* meant that the meaning of "semidet" must be settled between the two variants, but that it should first be clear what **`call_semidet/1`** actually guarantees: It is a lot more useful than what people *thought* Ulrich posted. For example, the definition that Jan gives:

```
call_semidet(Goal) :- 
        call_cleanup(Goal, Det=true), 
        (   Det == true 
        ->  true 
        ;   throw(error(mode_error(semidet,Goal),_)) 
        ).
```

works **only** with your second definition of "semidet".

Comment: Note that in Mercury answer and solutions are notions that can be used almost interchangeably since Mercury's answers are ground answers only.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! The issue with optimization was exactly what I had in mind, but my intent was that "aren't _both_ definitions well-defined and useful, deserving their own terminologies?" Maybe I'll rewrite my question tomorrow to clarify what I mean by "well-defined".

Comment: @mnish: Maybe better write a new question.

Comment: I agree with false: it is best to file a new question, since changing the question would also require changes in existing answers.

Answer (score 6):

The classification currently being used e.g. in SWI-Prolog is, as @mat mentioned, taken from Mercury. The mode names used (`det`, `semidet`, `multi`, and `nondet`) are very poor (and also insufficient) choices. They are not only abbreviations but require new users to lookup the documentation to understand their meaning! Ironically, the description of the meaning of each of these modes already suggests the best non-abbreviated and clear names. Remembering that we're talking about the *number of solutions*: `zero`, `one`, `zero_or_one`, `zero_or_more`, `one_or_more` (and possibly, due to its usefulness, `error`, which can be used to indicate that a given call mode results in an error). These are, btw, the mode names in use in Logtalk.

Mixing the specification of the number of solutions for a predicate (in a given mode) with issues with leftover choice-points is also a poor choice, ridden with ambiguity, as @mat also described. Code optimization issues are orthogonal to the specification of the number of solutions. Also, any mode other than `zero` may leave a spurious choice-point when the solutions are exhausted. Thus, this is more general than just a distinction between the poorly named `det` and `semidet` modes.

Comment: `call_semidet/1` is about answers, not solutions.

Comment: @false Neither the question or my answer is about the `call_semidet/1` predicate. Moreover, although both the question and the answers so far talk about *solutions*, a distinction can be made between *solutions*, *answers*, and *proofs*. But that requires precise definitions for these terms and a public consensus about those definitions. Currently, these terms are often used in a liberal way. In that regard, Logtalk describes in fact the second argument in predicate `mode/2` directives as the *number of proofs*, which follows naturally from the way the inference engine works.

Comment: Thank you very much, your point taken, but I have another point regarding "ambiguity" of choicepoints. It seems to me that choicepoints are a well-defined ISO concept independent of particular implementation. But maybe I need to understand precisely what `call_cleanup/2` does.

Comment: @mnish: See [this definition](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/cleanup) which is the best so far. For any questions, use a new SO-question.

Comment: @false: Oh, so an implementation is allowed to call clean-up at implementation-dependent moments. Then my point about SWI's definition doesn't seem very relevant. Hmm, I'm a bit confused..

Comment: @mnish: Again: For any questions, use a new SO-question.