# SWI: Semideterminate behavior : random/3 in call/1 context?

Tags: loops, prolog, call, deterministic

This was my initial bump-up with the notion of determinacy in Prolog :
[Why does Prolog does not backtrack on comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916606/why-does-prolog-does-not-backtrack-on-comparison/48916791?noredirect=1#comment84840684_48916791)

I also found this discussion interesting : 
[Has the notion of 'semidet' in Prolog settled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804667/has-the-notion-of-semidet-in-prolog-settled)

I wanted to implement more general loop construct (that behave like findall) :
(BTW: findall source seem weird, cant understand what this '$....' is all about).

```
fact(1,2).

loop(0,_,RV,RV) :- !.
loop(I, Goal, Acc, RV) :- I > 0, NI is I - 1, call(Goal), Goal =.. Lst, last(Lst,Item),  writeln(Item), loop(NI, Goal, [Item|Acc], RV).
```

As you can see it works in the general case :

```
?- loop(3,fact(1,R), [], RV).
2
2
2
R = 2,
RV = [2, 2, 2].
```

And again balks-up on random/3 :

```
?- loop(3,random(1,10,R), [], RV).
9
false.
```

I expected samidet behavior to hold only in the current call-context not when called recursively ? 
(BTW, swi-docs say that random/3 is det and random_between/3 is semidet. Both fail in the same way).

On the other hand if I do random directly rather than via call/1 it works !!!

This is the code from which I decided to abstract 'loop' (playing with ugraph lib) :

```
rand_edges(0, _, _, E, E) :- !.
rand_edges(I, RF, RT, E, RV) :- I > 0, NI is I - 1, random(RF,RT,R1), random(RF,RT,R2), rand_edges(NI, RF, RT, [R1-R2|E], RV).
rand_edges(I, RangeFrom, RangeTo,  Edges) :- rand_edges(I, RangeFrom, RangeTo, [], Edges).
rand_edges(I, Edges) :- rand_edges(I, 1, 10, [], Edges).
```

see it working :

```
?- rand_edges(5,E).
E = [5-5, 9-7, 2-2, 2-7, 3-5].
```

Why random/3 doesn't work in call/1 context ? But works as direct call ?

BTW, I just happen to stumble upon random/3, is there other predicates that will behave like random/3 ?

---

As per Taku :

```
 loop(0,_,RV,RV) :- !.
 loop(I, Goal, Acc, RV) :- 
     I > 0, NI is I - 1, call(Goal), Goal =.. Lst,
     %extract the result of the last call in Item, then substitute the last Var with new un-unified Var
     reverse(Lst,[Item|T]), reverse([_NewVar|T], NewLst),
     NewGoal =.. NewLst, %build a goal with the new-Var
     loop(NI, NewGoal, [Item|Acc], RV).
 loop(I, Goal, RV) :- loop(I, Goal, [], RV).



 ?- loop(5, random(1,10,_R), RV).
 _R = 7,
 RV = [4, 9, 8, 2, 7].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because once `R` of `random(1,10,R)` becomes ground(bound to a value), 
no longer R cannot be changed. 
At recursion call of `loop(NI, Goal, [Item|Acc], RV)` part ,
 `Goal` is patternmatched to `random(1,10,9)` actually and `9` cannnot be changed.

you should make this `9` change to free variable.

this code will work as you intended.

```
    loop(0,_,RV,RV) :- !.
    loop(I, Goal, Acc, RV) :- 
    I > 0, 
    NI is I - 1, 
    call(Goal), 
    Goal =.. Lst, 
    last(Lst,Item),  
    writeln(Item), 
    nth1(1, Lst, First),
    nth1(2,Lst,Second),
    nth1(3,Lst,Third),
    Goal2 =.. [First,Second,Third,NewRand],
    loop(NI, Goal2, [Item|Acc], RV).

    ?- loop(5,random(1,10,R),[],RV).
    7
    9
    2
    4
    2
    R = 7,
    RV = [2, 4, 2, 9, 7].
```